# How to get video output from didOutputSampleBuffer properly?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, avcapturesession

I'm trying to get every frame from the front camera according to this page: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1702/_index.html.

I also pasted my code here:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.captureSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
    self.captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium;
    NSAssert([self checkDeviceAuthorizationStatus], @"authorization failed");

    self.sessionQueue = dispatch_queue_create(SESSION_QUEUE_LABEL, DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
    dispatch_async(self.sessionQueue, ^{
        NSAssert([self findCamera:YES], @"get camera failed");
        NSAssert([self attachCameraToCaptureSession], @"get input failed");
        NSAssert([self setupVideoOutput], @"get output failed");
    });
}


- (BOOL) findCamera : (BOOL)useFrontCamera {
    AVCaptureDevice *camera = nil;
    NSArray *devices = [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

    for (AVCaptureDevice *device in devices) {
        if (useFrontCamera && AVCaptureDevicePositionFront == [device position]) {
            camera = device;
        } else if (!useFrontCamera && AVCaptureDevicePositionBack == [device position]) {
            camera = device;
        }
    }

    if (nil != camera) {
        if ([camera lockForConfiguration:nil]) {
            [camera setActiveVideoMinFrameDuration:CMTimeMake(1, 10)];
            [camera setActiveVideoMaxFrameDuration:CMTimeMake(1, 30)];
            [camera unlockForConfiguration];
        }
        self.camera = camera;
    }
    return (nil != self.camera);
}

- (BOOL) attachCameraToCaptureSession {
    NSAssert(nil != self.camera, @"no camera");
    NSAssert(nil != self.captureSession, @"no session");

    self.cameraInput = nil;
    NSError *error = nil;
    self.cameraInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:self.camera error:&error];

    if (nil != error) {
        NSLog(@"attach camera to session error: %@", error);
        return false;
    }

    if ([self.captureSession canAddInput:self.cameraInput]) {
        [self.captureSession addInput:self.cameraInput];
    } else {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

- (BOOL)setupVideoOutput {
    self.videoOutput = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];
    self.captureQueue = dispatch_queue_create(CAPTURE_QUEUE_LABEL, DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
    [self.videoOutput setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:self.captureQueue];
    self.videoOutput.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = NO;
    self.videoOutput.videoSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt: kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA ] forKey:(id)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey];
    if ([self.captureSession canAddOutput:self.videoOutput]) {
        [self.captureSession addOutput:self.videoOutput];
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

then I tried to get frames from the didOutputSampleBuffer function, but the UIImage is always nil.

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection {
    if (captureOutput == self.videoOutput) {
        NSLog(@"ok");
        dispatch_async(self.sessionQueue, ^{
            if (sampleBuffer) {
                UIImage *image = [ViewController imageFromSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer];
                NSLog(@"%@", image);
            }
        });
    } else {
        NSLog(@"not ok");
    }
}
```

The imageFromSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer function is the same to the one in the linked I pasted at first.

Besides, there's always the error from imageFromSampleBuffer::

: CGBitmapContextCreateImage: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.

Can anyone tell me why? Thanks!

My phone is iPhone5s and iOS8.1.

Comment: What do you want to do with so many UIImages? You'll run out of memory within two or three seconds. I'm pretty sure you have to choose a different approach. But to help you, we would need additional information about what you want to do with the captured images.

Comment: I wanna get the video data output and upload it to a cloud API. Since the API only takes UIImage as the parameter, so I need to change the sampleBuffer to UIImage.

Comment: I don't think I will run out of the memory within 2 or 3 seconds, since I have another app that also change the sampleBuffer from the method to UIImage, and it can keep running for at least 10 seconds.

Comment: It of course depends on your video resolution and frame rate. UIImage instances are uncompressed. In its uncompressed format, Full HD (1080p) produces approx. 380 MByte per second (1920 x 1080 x 3 x 60, i.e. width x height x bytes per pixel x fps) and will fill the 1 GByte memory of an iPhone 5 or later in less than 3 seconds. On an earlier phone, you'll fill it in half the time. You would need to have an incredibly fast network connection to write that amount of data to a cloud API in real-time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not just use `sampleBuffer` in another operation queue as you do with `dispatch_async`. This object can be already freed at the moment it is used by `imageFromSampleBuffer`. You have to choose from 2 approaches:

1. Use buffer in the same queue (thread) like it is in the sample you referred to.
2. Retain (or copy) it for farther usage. A good example can be found here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/RosyWriter/Introduction/Intro.html (look to the `captureOutput:...` method in the `RosyWriterVideoProcessor.m`).

Comment: Thanks. I just remove dispatch_async(self.sessionQueue, block) from captureOutput and it works.

Answer (score 0):

use this method to get every second frame from video url...Hope this will help you

```
-(void)generateThumbImage : (NSURL *)url
{
    // NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filepath];

    AVAsset *asset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:url];
    AVAssetImageGenerator *imageGenerator = [[AVAssetImageGenerator  alloc]initWithAsset:asset];
    imageGenerator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform=YES;

    CMTime time1 = [asset duration];

    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        CMTime time = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(i,30);
        CGImageRef imageRef = [imageGenerator copyCGImageAtTime:time actualTime:NULL error:NULL];
        UIImage *thumbnail = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
        CGImageRelease(imageRef);  // CGImageRef won't be released by ARC

        [arrayImages addObject:thumbnail];
    }
_imageView1.image=[arrayImages objectAtIndex:0];
_imageView2.image=[arrayImages objectAtIndex:1];
_imageView3.image=[arrayImages objectAtIndex:2];
_imageView4.image=[arrayImages objectAtIndex:3];
_imageView5.image=[arrayImages objectAtIndex:4];
NSLog(@"Image array:::::%@",arrayImages);

}
```

Comment: Since it doesn't get any data from camera, where should I put this code?